# Revert all commits by a specific author since specific time

Tags: git, git-revert

I want to revert all commits by a specific author since 4 days ago. How do I do it?

To get all sha1s (with a bit of noise) I can use this:

```
git log --author=Mohsen --pretty=one --since=4.days
```

Comment: If you are using github, the network view might be able to show you where you need to `git reset` to.  Also, do you want to `revert` or `reset`?  They are a little different.

Comment: There are other commits from other people. I don't want to reset back

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to give `format:%H` to `git log` and use a loop:

```
for sha in `git log --pretty=format:%H --author=Mohsen --since=4.days`; do
  git revert --no-edit $sha
done
```

This will create one commit per revert. Suppress the `--no-edit` option to modify interactively the commit message on each revert.

Or, if you want to make one big revert commit:

```
for sha in `git log --pretty=format:%H`; do sharange="$sharange $sha"; done
git revert $sharange --no-commit
git commit -m "reverted commits $sharange"
```

Comment: Thanks you! But it doesn't really stop when there is a conflict.

Comment: it does, if for one revert there is a conflict you'll be stopped and be allowed to continue with `git revert --continue`

Comment: Awesome answer, but I need to do a bit more commands in it. I need to accept —theirs changes if there is a conflict and if it was merge I need to use “git revert $sha -m 1;” can you help me with it?

Comment: You can do the single big revert commit and accept the change by hand?

Comment: After “git revert $sharange —no-commit” I got error - Commit “sha” is a merge but no -m option was given. Revert failed

Comment: I have merges in my branch and I need to revert them to

Comment: Then did you try to put the `-m` option?