# SVN: Can I revert all commits of a specific user?

Tags: svn

I found this

[Revert all commits by a specific author since specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935750/revert-all-commits-by-a-specific-author-since-specific-time)

Somebody knows how can I make the same thing in SVN

Thanks for all

Comment: Identify the author and revert his commits. What have you tried?

Comment: Finally we did that you say, localize author and reverts his commits. But there would be some possibility to make this in one sentence? something like "svn revert --author".

Comment: No, there is no such one-liner neither in Git nor in SVN. You should write a script for that.

Comment: ok! Thank you @bahrep